# how to callback after store.sync are failure?

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs

```
    function onButtonClick(){
               var grid = Ext.getCmp('mygridpanel')
               var row = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];
               var txtVehicleID = Ext.getCmp('txtVehicleID').getValue();
               var txtPlat_No = Ext.getCmp('txtPlat_No').getValue();
               console.log(txtVehicleID);

                var record = UserStore.findRecord('_id', txtVehicleID);
                record.set('_id', txtVehicleID);
                record.set('Plat_No',txtPlat_No);

                UserStore.sync({
                    success: function(batch) {
                                Ext.MessageBox.show({
                                    title: "Information",
                                    msg: batch.operations[0].request.scope.reader.jsonData["message"],
                                    icon: Ext.MessageBox.INFO,
                                    buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OK,
                                    fn: function(buttonId) {
                                        if (buttonId === "ok") {
                                            EditWin.close();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });  
                    },
                        failure: function(batch){
                                       Ext.MessageBox.show({
                                    title: "Error",
                                    msg: batch.operations[0].request.scope.reader.jsonData["message"],
                                    icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR,
                                    buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OK,
                                    fn: function(buttonId) {
                                        if (buttonId === "ok") {
                                                // Call back at here
                                    EditWin.close();
                                        }
                                    }
                        });  

                    }
                });
                //console.log("clicked");
    }
```

how to callback after store.sync are failure ?

Comment: Handler for failure sync state you can define by `failure: function() { ... }` in config object, which you use as parameter in `store.sync()` method. But this I can see already in your code, so where is the problem?

Comment: @Akatum how to call back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UserStore.rejectChanges();
```

See http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-rejectChanges